# Alternatives to showing usernames in TFS

Tags: tfs

A recent TFS upgrade resulted in the TFS server moving to a different domain where our usernames have no correlation to our real names. As a result, when looking at the history of checkins or who has a file checked out - all we see are numbers and you need to find who has that username.

We can't be the only company with this problem. What solutions/alternatives have you found that make this "less" of a problem?

Comment: Hi rodey. Is it possible for your team to update their usernames in Active Directory in the new domain?  TFS will sync those periodically.  Also, what does the username actually look like?  Is it a SID (does it start with "S-" or is it just a number?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2010 this was not possible.

Fortunately, Microsoft responded to this popular complaint and introduced an option to set display name in TFS 11:

[image]